# Search table using cypress

Tags: javascript, html-table, automated-tests, cypress

Does Cypress work well with tables? I have a table where my newly added element is on the second page of the table. I would like to search the table if the element is not on the first page so that Cypress will click on page 2. Can I do it or do I have to use Javascript or something else?

Comment: Can you elaborate what "second page" means? A click-through link to another web page?

Comment: Yes, Record of the table is on the second page (I have to use pagination)

Comment: I try something like that                                           cy.get('table.table.table-striped.table-custom').get('tr').contains('searchingText').then(($tr) => {
            if ($tr.hasClass('active')) {
                cy.get('table.table.table-striped.table-custom').get('tr').contains('searchingText).siblings('td', {
                    force: true
                }).find('.form-control').select('Option1')               
            } else {              
                cy.get('div.form-group > ul.pagination.pull-right > li.next > span').click()
            }
        })

Comment: That is true, I wouldn't include that in a e2e test as it can be quite tricky and prone to errors. I myself tried such things in a couple of situations in the past but they turned into a headache in the long term, so removed them.

Answer (score 1):

This is called **`Conditional Testing`**, and is generally a **bad idea** for e2e tests.

[Here's the guide on the Cypress Docs about Conditional Testing](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing.html#)

Answer (score 0):

This is what i actually do if i want search whithin a table (In this case i click in every available button):

```js
 cy.get('.name_of_class_or_id_if_apply').then((table) => {
        //Obtain the quantity of rows
        var count_rows = table[0].childElementCount
            //Obatining the name of rows
            var aux_name_rows = table[0].classList.toString()
            for (var i = 0; i < count_rows; ++i) {
                //Obtaining the quantity of columns
                var count_columns = table[0].childNodes[i].childElementCount
                    //Obtaining the name of columns
                    var aux_name_columns = table[0].childNodes[i].classList.toString()
                    for (var j = 1; j < count_columns; ++j) {
                        //In my case i obtain the name of the buttons
                        var aux_name_columns_button = table[0].childNodes[i].childNodes[j].classList.toString()
                            //Checking if the button is clickeable
                            if (aux_name_columns_button == "your_class_button") {
                                //Obtaining the position click
                                var row_position_click = i + 1
                                    var column_position_click = j + 1
                                    cy.get(':nth-child(' + row_position_click + ') > :nth-child(' + column_position_click + ') > .class_of_object_clickeable').click()
    
                            }
                    }
            }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

This will helps

```
cy.xpath(columnInTable).each(
      ($e, index, $list) => {
        const text = $e.text()
        if (text.includes('yourDesiredColumnText')) {
//Do logic here
          }

        if (index === -1) {
          //goto 2nd page
        }
      }
    )
  }
```